# Not able to export variable using system in awk

Tags: linux, shell, awk, ksh

I am trying to parse a input xml file(shown below) using awk to get the user, password and instance to connect. I am trying to export these values on shell so that I can use these in my script. print is showing correct command but somehow system is not exporting it.
I am on linux KSH.

Input File

```
> cat aa.xml
<Parameters>
   <Parameter Name="USER" Value="DB9"/>
   <Parameter Name="PASSWORD" Value="DB9"/>
   <Parameter Name="INSTANCE" Value="P1"/>
</Parameters>
```

Code:

```
    > awk -F '\"' '/<Parameter Name/,//{ cmd="export " $(NF-3) "=" $(NF-1); system(cmd); print cmd}' aa.xml

export USER=DB9
export PASSWORD=DB9
export INSTANCE=P1

> echo $PASSWORD
```

Comment: You can't because one process (the instance of `awk` or worse the instance of the shell that it runs to execute a `system` command) can not affect the environment of another process (like the shell you invoked `awk` from). And this the massively duplicated in various places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `system(...)` there will be executed in a sub-process of the `awk` process, so whatever you do there will not affect the parent process--your shell. You can do this though:

```
. <(awk -F '\"' '/<Parameter Name/,//{ print "export " $(NF-3) "=" $(NF-1) }' aa.xml)
```

That is, `source` the output of `awk`, effectively running the `export` commands in your current shell.

Comment: It does in version `93u+ 2012-02-29`.